# Why does an inside loop not affect the outer loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose the following code:

```
my_list = [1,2,3]
for x in my_list:
     for y in my_list:
          print(x,y)
          #implicit next(my_list)
```

Why does the inner implicit next(my_list) not affect the outside loop?

Comment: `my_list` is not defined/set.

Comment: I corrected that, thank you

Comment: Do you want change  the list which you currently loop through in ?

Comment: you can't call `next` on a list

Comment: The [for statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) returns an "iterator" which is a container for a stream of data that returns one element at a time, so you are not iterating over the iterable (your list in this case) but instead over this container. As a result, the inner loop and outer loop are not actually iterating over the same object (even though the syntax makes it appear that way).

Comment: can the  *explicit* form of your code run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list is an iterable. You can call `iter(my_list)` on it to retrieve an iterator. This iterator holds a particular index into the list independently of other iterators.

`for x in my_list` actually works like

```
temp_iter1 = iter(my_list)
try:
    while True:
        x = next(temp_iter1)
        ... # Loop code
except StopIteration:
    pass
```